# Evaluation of integrals, where limits are in radians?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 2x \cdot \cos(x^2+2) \, dx$$

(Limits are in Radians)
Could anyone point me in the right direction, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the $u$-substitution $x^2=u$

Comment: @JohnLou : $u = x^2 + 2$ seems a bit simpler.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I probably would have then done $u+2 \to v$ or something. I always forgot to take it in one step.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 2x\cos\left(x^2+2\right)\,dx\overset{u=x^2+2}{\longrightarrow} \left. \int_2^3 \cos(u)\,du=\sin(u)\right|_2^3 \\[10pt]
= {} &\sin(3)-\sin(2)=2\cos\left(\frac{5}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx -0.768
\end{align}